# How should I achieve dynamic routing in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

[image]

**Also here is the actual output**
[image]

1. I want to create a dynamic routing which fetches the data from **Array of Object**
2. Here you can see I want to fetch data from subCategory and display the names on different page in the form of cards.

Here I am sharing my code with you guys.

**1. all-trades.component.ts**

```
 templateUrl: './all-trades.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-trades.component.css'],
})
export class AllTradesComponent implements OnInit {

// This is my Array of Object

  crops = [
    {
      name: 'Rice',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Basmati',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ammamore',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Wheat',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Durum',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Emmer',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }, {
      name: 'Barley',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Hulless Barley',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Barley Flakes',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  ]



  onChange(event, index, item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
    console.log(index, event, item);
  }

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  
}
```

**2. all-trades.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div
  fxLayout="row"
  fxLayout.lt-md="column"
  fxLayoutAlign="space-between start"
  fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="start stretch"
>
  <div class="container-outer" fxFlex="20">
    <div class="filters">
      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select Crop</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let crop of crops">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="crop.checked"
                (change)="onChange($event, i, crop)"
              >
                {{ crop.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>

      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select District</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let district of districts">
              <mat-checkbox>
                {{ district.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content container-outer" fxFlex="80">
    <mat-card
      class="crop-card"
      style="min-width: 17%"
      *ngFor="let crop of crops"
      [hidden]="!crop.checked"
    >
    <!-- I tried the logic here to navigate to sub-Category Array by its id.
    But I failed -->
      <a
        [routerLink]="['/all-trades', crop.id]"
        routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
      >
        <mat-card-header>
          <img
            mat-card-avatar
            class="example-header-image"
            src="/assets/icons/crops/{{ crop.name }}.PNG"
            alt="crop-image"
          />
          <mat-card-title>{{ crop.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>100 Kgs</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
      </a>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>PRICE</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Here You guys can see on my webpage there is couples of cards named as "RICE", "WHEAT", "BARLY" All just I want to do is by clicking on RICE my code should navigate to another component page and display the name of subCategory name from my Array of Object. Similarly, it should also work for "WHEAT" and "BARLEY" as well Example: When I click on Wheat Card it should navigate to different page and display the name of subCategory of Wheat section.

```
crops = [
    {
      name: 'Rice', <---- 1. Go here
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [ <-- 2. Go to subCategory and fetch the name of the "RICE" on different Page
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Basmati',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ammamore',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Wheat',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Durum',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Emmer',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }, {
      name: 'Barley',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Hulless Barley',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Barley Flakes',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your Array of object into a shared folder(if not create one directory with name shared)

create`Crop.ts` into shared folder

```
import {subcategory} from './subcategory';
export class Crop{
    checked:boolean
    name: string;
    comments: Subcategory[];
}
```

create
`subcategory.ts` into shared folder

```
export class subcategory{
id:string,
name:string,
isActive:boolean
}
```

create
`cropdata.ts` into shared folder

```
import {Crop} from './crop';

export const CROP: Crop[] = [
    {
      name: 'Rice',
      checked: true,
      subCategory:[ 
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Basmati',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ammamore',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Wheat',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Durum',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Emmer',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }, {
      name: 'Barley',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Hulless Barley',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Barley Flakes',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }
]
```

```
 [routerLink]="['/Cropdetail', crop.name]"
```

```
 {path:'Cropdetail/:name',component:CropdetailComponent},
```

And in Cropdetail.ts(cropdetail component)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  let name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    this.crop= this.cropservice.getCrop(name);
}
```

genrate service
`cropservice`

```
import {CROP} from '../shared/cropdata';

CropData:CROP
getCrop(name: string): CROP{
    return CropData.filter((crop) => (crop.name === name))[0];
}
```

and finally at to access subcategory in cropdetail.html
`{{Crop.subCategory}}`